# Accessing DOM Element properties in Chrome Development tools (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn JavaScript and I've found working in the Chrome Developer Tools console to be helpful. Here is my Codepen.

```
`http://codepen.io/mike_frontend/pen/egvvWg`
```

For example, when I call the variable paraOne, I get the p element and I can click and access the DOM properties. I can see the firstChild.nodeName is the label element. But when I run paraOne.firstElementChild, it comes back undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated.